# Images from AWS cloudfront URL are not getting loaded in react-native release build

Tags: react-native, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to create a react native app release apk using below command:-

```
1)react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle

2)gradlew assembleRelease
```

But in release build apk my images from amazon cloudfront are not getting loaded although in debug-apk everything was working fine

I also tried adding below cors policy for my s3 bucket:-

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "POST",
            "GET",
            "PUT"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

P.S:- All local images are getting loaded peoperly issue is with remote images only

still it is not working please provide some suggestion to resolve it

thank you